# Transfer data from table view cell inside a collection view cell, to another collection view cell [with picture!]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates, uicollectionview

I am working on an app where I'm stuck in a limbo between collection view cells and the contained table views within them.

My first collection view cell contains a table view with table view cells.
Each table view cell contain saved data and by selecting one cell two things should happen.

1. The collection view cell should change index to current +1
2. The table view cells data (in this case title and date) should be passed onto the new collection view cells header property.

One other aspect is that the table views are stored in a container view class. I'm not sure if this matter or not, but its one extra layer to pass the variables through.

So far this is where I get stuck

tableViewDidselectCode

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let header = LoadHeaderView()
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(forIndexPath: indexPath) as SavedTableViewCell
    header.titleString = cell.taskLabel.text!
    header.descriptionString = cell.clientLabel.text!
}
```

How do I pass this to

```
self -> ContainerView -> collectionCell[0] -> CollectionView -> collectionCell[1] -> tableView -> header?
```

[image: Symbolic setup for my problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table view has a dependency on the parent collection view cell. That means you need to pass a reference of the collection view cell to the table view on instantiation. I'd make a protocol.

```
protocol myTableViewCellDelegate {
  func updateMyCollectionViewCell
}

extension myCollectionViewCell: myTableViewCellDelegate {
  func updateMyCollectionViewCell {
    // update whatever you need to here
  }
}

extension myCollectionTableViewDelegate: UITableViewDelegate {
  // ...
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                      willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, 
                      forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // instantiate table view
    // pass self to tableview *as weak reference*
    myTableView.customDelegate = self
  }
  //...
}

extension myTableViewDelegate: UITableViewDelegate {
  //...
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
                 didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // instantiate table view cell
    // assuming you're not using custom cell class
    tableCell.updateMyCollectionViewCell()

    // if you are using custom cell class then the tableViewDelegate
    // will need to pass collectionView reference on to the cells
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks!

What a wonderful clear and well structured answer.

If this was Tinder, I'd give you a super like ;)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use a blocks to send information and any other actions.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html